# Update ID column depending on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where i need to update the ID field depending on a date column.

Table A

```
H_MEP_ID|_LoadDate                  |_EndDate                |ID
12312   |2015-04-19 12:14:52.733    |2016-06-16 17:19:56.613 |72
12312   |2016-06-16 17:19:53.403    |NULL                    |83
```

Table B

```
H_MEP_ID|MeasureDate|MeasureDateTime    |ID
12312   |2015-10-02 |2015-10-02 23:00   |NULL
12312   |2015-11-01 |2015-11-01 23:00   |NULL
12312   |2015-11-02 |2015-11-02 23:00   |NULL
12312   |2016-06-16 |2016-06-16 23:00   |NULL
```

How Table B should look like after the update script.

```
H_MEP_ID|MeasureDate|MeasureDateTime    |ID
12312   |2015-10-02 |2015-10-02 23:00   |72
12312   |2015-11-01 |2015-11-01 23:00   |72
12312   |2015-11-02 |2015-11-02 23:00   |72
12312   |2016-06-16 |2016-06-16 23:00   |83
```

Do someone have any advice how to proceed?

Table B has 111M rows, how could i split the query with a while loop on the MeasureDate field?

Comment: Please show us your best attempt at resolving this problem yourself.

Comment: You need to be more specific. I cant find how is the appropriate ID determined? Why are the first three values in ID column in Tbl_B_updated 72 and fourth value is 83?

Comment: I am not sure why the result should look like that, because in table A the LoadDate for ID = 83 is 2016-06-16 and in the result the MeasureDate is 2015-11-03. Just by the looks I would expect the ID in the result to be 72. Am I missing something?

Comment: If the row has an enddate all the measuredates before the enddate should get 72 in table b. And all the measuredates after enddate should get 83 in table b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   update b
    set 
    b.id=a.id
    from
    tablea a
    join
    tableb b
    on
    b.H_MEP_ID=a.H_MEP_ID
    and b.meaure_datetime between a.loaddate and isnull(a.enddate,getdate())
```

Comment: Table B has 111M rows, how could i split the query with a while loop on the MeasureDate field? Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please check this link to improve question and ask a new question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/